# Galois group of the simple extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K=Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$. Show that the extension is $K/Q$ is simple and also Galois extension. Determine its Galois group.

I showed that extension is simple because $K=Q(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})$
But I can not find its Galois group?

Comment: It's not $Q(\sqrt{3+5})$, but $Q(\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5})$

Comment: @Crostul they are same

Comment: Absolutely not: $\sqrt{3+5}=\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}$, so $Q(\sqrt{3+5})=Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @corciacandy I've corrected the typo Crostul points out; if this really is not what was intended, please revert it (ideally with some explanation, because as Crostul points out the statement was not correct as written).

Comment: sorry you are right it is my carelessness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that  any $\sigma \in \mathrm {Aut} L$ is determined by the images of $\sigma (\sqrt{3})$ and $\sigma (\sqrt 5)$ then the possibilities are $\sigma (\sqrt 3) \in \{-\sqrt 3, \sqrt 3 \}$ and $\sigma (\sqrt 5) \in \{-\sqrt 5, \sqrt 5\}$.

Can you see how this is related to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Actually I think that this Galois group isomorphic to Klein 4 group

Comment: Have you built the table of isomorphims?

Comment: actually no, I look at the order of elements in G

Comment: There are only two groups of order $4$, apart from isomorphisms: $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. Now if you check the order of each element then you'll notice that they all have order $2$, what does that say?

Comment: Notice that the Klein group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, because all of its elements have order $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sigma$ be a Galois automorphism of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$. What can $\sigma(\sqrt{3})$ be ? (Hint: $x = \sqrt(3)$ satisfies $x^2-3 = 0$, and $\sigma$ is a field automorphism stabilizing $\mathbb Q$, so that $y = \sigma(x)$ must satisfy the same equation). Same question for $\sqrt{5}$.

Now you have a maximum set of a few candidates for Galois automorphisms. You only need to prove that all of them actually are Galois automorphisms. This should not be the hardest part.

Comment: $\sigma(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3} or -\sqrt{3}$ isn't it?

So $|G| =4$

Comment: You still need to prove that these four automorphisms do exist, but yes, this is the idea.

Comment: one more question, why did you choose $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt5$.. can I choose $\sqrt3 + \sqrt5$

Comment: Yes, you can. But you need to write down its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.