# Are all finite extensions of perfect fields cyclic?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I am not well trained in number theory. If there is any mistake, please straightly edit this question or devote me if the question is too trivial.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field, 
a field $k$ is perfect iff $char(k)=0$ or $char(k)=p>0$ with Frobenius endomorphism being an isomorphism of $k$.

I think at least the Pete L. Clark's answer in [Are all extensions of finite fields cyclic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38197/are-all-extensions-of-finite-fields-cyclic) having gently solved the $char(k)=p>0$ case of the problem, but the same method can not be applied to characteristic zero cases.

Comment: Addendum: This is a fact mentioned in Serre's $\it{Local\,\, Field}$, giving the motivation for a claim. Let $k_{n}$ be a cyclic extension of $k$ of degree $n$ and $F^{n}$ be the generator of $G_{k_{n}/k}$. This claim is, if $k$ is perfect and $k^{sep}$ is the union of all cyclic extensions $k^{n}$ for all $n$ with $F^{mn}|_{k_{n}}=F^{n}$, then 
$k$ is a quasi-finite field.

Comment: There are noncyclic extensions of fields of characteristic zero.

Comment: Not to mention that your link does not solve the problem, since not every perfect field of positive characteristic is finite...

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I will grateful if you can provide any explicit example for a finite extension of a characteristic zero field with Galois group which is not cyclic, and I think a counterexample is also an answer for this problem. I failed to find an example at present.

Comment: Try $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3) / \Bbb Q$

Comment: @Watson As far as I’m concerned, you gave a counterexample for this claim, which means the answer to this question should be NO! Thanks a lot. As for the calculations, I think it is the same manner with the calculations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267913/galois-group-of-the-simple-extension)